# ¿Cómo resaltar el texto en amarillo con javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Quisiera que cuando el usuario ingresara un número este se comparara con el **array** y si el número es menor del que indicó el usuario, se escriba y resalte el número en un **background** amarillo, y si no, que se se escriba normalmente.

**Adjunto la parte del código:**

`JS`

```
 var tiempoC = document.getElementById("tiempoC");
/*tiempoC guarda la variable del tiempo "numero" que se compara con los datos de mi matriz*/
var comparacion = document.getElementById("comparación");
comparacion.addEventListener("click", resaltar);
//funcion para resaltar valores menores de lo indicado
function resaltar() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
      if (tiempoC>fullMatriz[i][j]) {
        ¿?
      }
      else {
        document.write(fullMatriz[i][j] + "------");
      }
    }
    document.write("</br>");
  }
}
```

`HTML`

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="ejecutarautomatica1.js"></script>
    <p>Este es el subprogrma para marcar los tiempos menores al ingresado aquí abajo
      <br/>ingrese el tiempo aqui abajo
      <br/><input type="text" id="tiempoC"/>
      <input type="button" value="iniciar comparación" width="300" height="50" id="comparation"/>

    </p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: mayúsculas == gritar. Edita el título, gracias :D

Comment: ¿Qué estilo de "resaltado" buscas?, ¿Algún ejemplo?

Comment: ¿Podrías por favor añadir parte del HTML y CSS que usas en este problema?

Comment: añadí el html y css no use aun

Answer (score 1):

utiliza la etiqueta mark

en css

```
mark{
    background-color:yellow;
   color:black
 }
```

en html

```
<mark> mi texto resaltado</mark>
```

en tu codigo javascript , cuando tengas que enseñar la palabra correspondiente , le inyectas el mark, como haces con el br

en lugar de esto

```
else {
        document.write(fullMatriz[i][j] + "------");
      }
```

prueba con esto

```
comparacion.innerHTML="<mark>texto</mark>"
```

si te da problemas la etiqueta mark , prueba con la etiqueta "span"

Answer (score 1):

podrias crear un template ya con los estilos e insertarlo si se cumple tu condicion

```
let texto = "" // lo que quieras mostrar
let template =`
<span style="background:yellow; color:black;">${texto}</span>
`;
//insertas el template
let resultado = document.getElementByid('elemeto') // selecciones el elemnto donde quieres mostrar la respuesta
resultado.innerHtml = template;
```

Answer (score 1):

espero que te sea de utilidad:

He mantenido el código que proporcionaste, pero sustituido el if por la operación:

```js
tiempoC>fullMatriz[i][j] ? "class='classMenorChecked'>":">"
```

evalúa si tiempoC es mayor y en ese caso establece la classMenorChecked al estilo del div, es decir;
Si tiempoC == 5 y fullMatriz[3][5] == 4, se construye el siguiente div:

```
   "<div class="classMenorChecked">5</div>"
```

O bien, si tiempoC == 5 y fullMatriz[3][5] == 5, entonces se construye:

```
    "<div>5</div>"
```

Generando la siguiente solución:

```js
var tiempoC = document.getElementById("tiempoC");
/*tiempoC guarda la variable del tiempo "numero" que se compara con los datos de mi matriz*/
var comparacion = document.getElementById("comparación");
comparacion.addEventListener("click", resaltar);
//funcion para resaltar valores menores de lo indicado
function resaltar() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        document.write("<div"    // Utilizaremos la etiqueta div para darle un formato a algo 
            + (tiempoC>fullMatriz[i][j] ? "class='classMenorChecked'>":">") // se evalúa y devuelve si debe o no tener class-yellow
            +fullMatriz[i][j] // Concatenamos el valor
            + "------</div>"  // finalmente concatenamos el final del div
        );

    }
    document.write("</br>");
  }
}
```

Supongamos, que classMenorChecked esta en un fichero css

```css
.classMenorChecked{
    background-color : yellow; 
    color : black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var tiempoC = document.getElementById("tiempoC");
var comparacion = document.getElementById("comparación");
comparacion.addEventListener("click", resaltar);
//funcion para resaltar valores menores de lo indicado
function resaltar() {

var indiceI="";


var indiceY=";

  for (var i = 0; i < 17; i++) {

for (var j = 0; j < 9; j++) {

    if (tiempoC>fullMatriz[i][j]) {

  indiceI=i;

        indiceY=j;

       break; 

      }

    }

  }

if(indiceY!=""){
    document.write(fullMatriz[indiceI][indiceY] + "------");
}
```

Comment: Pro favor agrega una descripcion de que fue lo que hiciste para que el usuario pueda entender tu respuesta.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, pero te sugerimos revisar [answer], edita tu respuesta, saludos..

Answer (score 0):

Holaa para no complicarte usando un script externo de css puedes usar esto añade una etiqueta SPAN y ahi añade el marcado:

```js
    var tiempoC = document.getElementById("tiempoC"),
    numero = document.getElementById("numero");

    /*tiempoC guarda la variable del tiempo "numero" que se compara con los datos de mi matriz*/
    var comparacion = document.getElementById("comparation");
    comparacion.addEventListener("click", resaltar);
    //funcion para resaltar valores menores de lo indicado
    function resaltar() {

      for (var i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
          if (tiempoC>fullMatriz[i][j]) {
          
            numero.innerHTML(tiempoC);
            numero.style.backgroundColor = '#F7DC6F';
            
          }
          else {
          
            numero.innerHTML(tiempoC);
            document.write(fullMatriz[i][j] + "------");
          }
        }
        document.write("</br>");
      }
    }
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <script src="ejecutarautomatica1.js"></script>
        <p>Este es el subprogrma para marcar los tiempos menores al ingresado aquí abajo
          <br/>ingrese el tiempo aqui abajo
          <br/><input type="text" id="tiempoC"/>
          <br><span id='numero'></span>
          <input type="button" value="iniciar comparación" width="300" height="50" id="comparation"/>

        </p>

      </body>
    </html>
```